# Создание парсера YouTube трендов

Tags: python, парсер, youtube, requests, bs4

Создаю парсер на Python 3.6.Код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("""https://""" + """www.youtube.com/feed/trending""")
data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

all_videos = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'style-scope ytd-video-meta-block', 'id': 'metadata-line'})

print(all_videos)

for video in all_videos:
    link = video.find('span', {"class": "style-scope ytd-video-renderer-score"})
    print(link.string)
```

Парсер должен выводить количество просмотров видео,но парсер не выводит ничего.Переменная(массив)  `all_videos` всегда пустой.Почему массив `all_videos` всегда пустой, и как его заполнить,что бы потом можно было его использовать для просмотров просмотров видео?

UPD1 Код с использованием подсказки @gil9red:

```
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import requests
        import sys

        r = requests.get("""https://""" + """www.youtube.com/feed/trending""")
        data = r.text

        f = open('text.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        f.write(data)
        f.close()
        f = open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
        text = f.read()
        f.close()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

        all_videos = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'style-scope ytd-video-meta-block', 'id': 'metadata-line'})

        print(all_videos)

        for video in all_videos:
            link = video.find('span', {"class": "style-scope ytd-video-renderer-score"})
            print(link.string)
```

UPD2 Код с использованием подсказки @gil9red:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("""https://""" + """www.youtube.com/feed/trending""")
data = r.text

f = open('text.html', 'wb')
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
f = open('text.html', 'r',encoding = 'utf-8')
text = f.read()
f.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

all_videos = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'style-scope ytd-video-meta-block', 'id': 'metadata-line'})

print(all_videos)

for video in all_videos:
    link = video.find('span', {"class": "style-scope ytd-video-renderer-score"})
    print(link.string)
```

Comment: Возможно, содержимое страницы не статичное приходит, а формируется через ajax и javascript. Попробуйте сохранить `r.text` в файл и поиска в нем атрибуты для `all_videos`

Comment: @gil9red Не помогло, массив всё равно пуст=((

Comment: Может у кого-нибудь есть ссылки на похожие вопросы,материалы.Очень бы помогло.

Comment: Попробуйте вот так сохранить: `open('rs.html', 'wb').write(r.content)`. `r.text` содержит уже строку, а чтобы сохранять в файл может понадобиться указывать кодировку, другое дело `r.content` -- это уже байты и достаточно открыть файл в бинарном режиме и вписать байты. Кст, хотел подсказать, что кроме `requests` у вас будет еще вариант кода с selenium, мой пример с поиском и просмотром на ютубе: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f071aadf145a168f6929a88d3d1e649f03852334/selenium__examples/search_and_watch_cats_on_youtube/main.py

Comment: @gil9red Правильно ли я написал код, который вы мне подсказали?Если да, то опять же нечего не сработало =((.То-есть обязательно selenium использовать, или всё таки ошибка в моём коде??

Comment: Эмм, вы не поняли, я говорил сохранить страницу в 'text.html' только для того чтобы вы проверили что данные, что вы ищите скриптом там есть и только :) Не нужно данные гонять в файл, из файл и в парсер -- это смысла не имеет. Возможно, без selenium не обойтись. Проверьте сначала что с requests'ом не выйдет. Еще, умеете работать с инспектором в браузерах? У меня, на Firefox, это кнопка F12, после которой откроется панель на которой можно посмотреть код страницы, консоль, запросы по сети с текущей страницей и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура хтмл страницы одного видео из трендов ютюба в интернете:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После сохранения в html файл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Они отличаются по-этому изменяем название классов:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("""https://""" + """www.youtube.com/feed/trending""")
data = r.text

f = open('text.html', 'wb')
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
f = open('text.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
text = f.read()
f.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

all_videos = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'yt-lockup-meta '})


for video in all_videos:
    link = video.find('ul', {"class": "yt-lockup-meta-info"})
    print(link.get_text())
```

P.S Не обязательно брать текст с файла, так как

```
data = f.read()
```